# How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\frac{e}{e-1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to prove that 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\frac{e}{e-1}$$

Thank in advances.

Comment: Hi ! This look like a homework question : tell us what you've done and where you are stuck so users will give you usefull hints.